# How to pass a return value of operation to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trailblazer

I've been spent a lot of time and still trying figure out how to pass a result(return) of operation to my view. As regarding documentation I created cell, operation and view folders inside concepts folder. I'm working with Search app, here is my cell/show.rb

```
module Search::Cell
  class Show < Trailblazer::Cell
  end
end
```

Here is view/show.rb

```
<h1> Hello! </h1>
#how to pass result here?
<a href="/search">Return back</a>
```

My operation/show.rb

```
require "trailblazer/operation"

module Search::Operation
  class Show < Trailblazer::Operation
    step    :hello_world!
    fail    :log_error

    def hello_world!(options, search_word)
      puts "Hello, Trailblazer!"
      search_word = search_word[:params]
      search_word.downcase!
      true
    end

    def log_error
      p "Some error happened!!"
      true
    end
  end
end
```

And search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    search_word = params[:text]
    if search_word.present?
      Search::Operation::Show.(params: search_word)
      render html: cell(Search::Cell::Show).()
    else
      render html: cell(Search::Cell::Index).()
    end
  end 
end
```

Which variable or method should I use to pass result from operation (hello_world! method to view? I tried different things (heard some about ctx variable also tried instance variable like in common rails app) and debugging a lot with pry and didn't solve it. Please, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://trailblazer.to/gems/cells/getting-started.html#gemscellsgetting-startedmd-343), it seems like you have two options.

1. Pass the result of your operation as the **"model"** and access it via the model variable that is accessible in the cell's template.

```rb
    class SearchController < ApplicationController
      def index
        search_word = params[:text]
        if search_word.present?
          result = Search::Operation::Show.(params: search_word)
          render html: cell(Search::Cell::Show, result)
        else
          render html: cell(Search::Cell::Index)
        end
      end 
    end
```

And then in your template, assuming you're using ERB:

```
    <h1> Hello! </h1>
    The result is <%= model %>
    <a href="/search">Return back</a>
```

2. Pass the result of your operation within the context and access it through a method defined in the cell class.

```rb
    class SearchController < ApplicationController
      def index
        search_word = params[:text]
        if search_word.present?
          result = Search::Operation::Show.(params: search_word)
          render html: cell(Search::Cell::Show, nil, result: result)
        else
          render html: cell(Search::Cell::Index)
        end
      end 
    end
```

And then in your cell class:

```rb
    module Search::Cell
      class Show < Trailblazer::Cell
        def my_result
          #here is the logic you need to do with your result
          context[:result]
        end
      end
    end
```

And then in your template, assuming you're using ERB:

```
    <h1> Hello! </h1>
    The result is <%= my_result %>
    <a href="/search">Return back</a>
```

Comment: From the first example I receive "The result is #", I inspected it with pry and here is output " <Result:true #<Trailblazer::Context::IndifferentAccess:0x0000562ccde78358 @wrapped_options={:params=>"array"}, @mutable_options={}, @aliases={}>"

Comment: So, in your operation, according to the [docs](http://trailblazer.to/gems/operation/2.0/#state-and-result) you need to write to the `options` object the result of your operation, and then use it wherever you need to. 

In this case your operation could do something like `options['search_word'] = search_word.downcase` and then in the template `The result is <%= model['search_word'] %>`

Comment: In this case empty value of 'search_word': <Result:true #<Trailblazer::Context::IndifferentAccess:0x000055bd7cbdb8b8 @wrapped_options={:params=>"array"}, @mutable_options={"search_word"=>nil}, @aliases={}> >

Comment: One more question: to make some custom of this output I need to create logic in custom cell method? and then invoke it in view?

Comment: Yes, if you mean presentation logic, you can create a method in the cell and then invoke it in the template